# How does one create a MongoDB document with a child array using Yesod's Persistent?

Tags: haskell, mongodb, yesod

I am attempting to create a Persistent type that is modeled something like:

```
MyModel
    something Text
    somethingElse [Int]
```

and I get an error:

> Illegal type constructor or class name: `[Int]'
>       When splicing a TH declaration:
>         data MyModel
>       = MyModel {myModelSomething :: Text, myModelSomethingElse ::
>   [Int]}
>       deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you included a minimal test-case for reproducing your error: the exact contents of a file + the command-line you use.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a limitation of the Persistent syntax. To get around it, define a type synonym in your Haskell code (before the mkPersist call) like:

```
type Ints = [Int]
```

Then replace `[Int]` with `Ints` in your declaration, it should work.

Comment: I get a "No instance for (PersistField Ints) arising from a use of fromPersistValue.  Any ideas?

Comment: I personally haven't used the MongoDB backend, so I don't know all the details, but I know that we added the `PersistList` constructor to assist with this case. My guess is you should do something instead like `newtype Ints = Ints [Int]` and then declare a `PersistField` for it using `PersistList`. You may want to write to the Yesod mailing list if you run into more trouble.